# Laravel, how to redirect as 301 and 302

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, http-status-codes

I cannot find info for redirecting as 301/302 in the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing).

In my routes.php file I use:

```
Route::get('foo', function(){ 
    return Redirect::to('/bar'); 
});
```

Is this a 301 or 302 by default? Is there a way to set it manually? Any idea why this would be omitted from the docs?

Comment: Can use `Route::redirect` or `Route::permanentRedirect` Updated docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#redirect-routes

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Whenever you are unsure, you can have a look at Laravel's API documentation with the source code. The [Redirector class](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html) defines a `$status = 302` as default value.

You can define the status code with the `to()` method:

```
Route::get('foo', function(){ 
    return Redirect::to('/bar', 301); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the bumb. Would I be able to do the same with `Redirect::action`?

Comment: @Jerodev - Yes it seems so, see http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_action.

Comment: With Laravel 5 you can now also use the simple function redirect('/bar', 301).

Comment: You may also include a route name too, `redirect(null, 301)->route('name')`

Answer (score 18):

I update the answer for Laravel 5! 
Now you can find on docs [redirect helper](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-redirect):

```
return redirect('/home');

return redirect()->route('route.name');
```

As usual.. whenever you are unsure, you can have a look at Laravel's [API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/) with the source code. The [Redirector class](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html) defines a $status = 302 as default value (302 is a temporary redirect).

If you wish have a permanent URL redirection ([HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)), you can define the status code with the [redirect() function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects):

```
Route::get('foo', function(){ 
    return redirect('/bar', 301); 
});
```

Comment: There is a way to redirect to a named route using 301? Probably `return redirect()->route('series')->status(301);` but I am not sure.

Comment: Just happened to look at JCarlos comment while I was doing something similar: passing the status as a 3rd parameter in named routes seems to be working for me.

Comment: `->status(301)` did not work for me.  Instead I had to do `return redirect()->route('series', [], 301);` The second array is any parameters needed for a route, i.e. slug or id.

Comment: you should be able to do `return redirect()->route('series')->setStatusCode(301);`

Answer (score 9):

martinstoeckli's answer is good for static urls, but for dynmaic urls you can use the following.

### For Dynamic URLs

```
Route::get('foo/{id}', function($id){ 
    return Redirect::to($id, 301); 
});
```

**Live Example (my use case)**

```
Route::get('ifsc-code-of-{bank}', function($bank){ 
    return Redirect::to($bank, 301); 
});
```

This will redirect
http://swiftifsccode.com/ifsc-code-of-sbi to http://swiftifsccode.com/sbi

**One more Example**

```
Route::get('amp/ifsc-code-of-{bank}', function($bank){ 
    return Redirect::to('amp/'.$bank, 301); 
});
```

This will redirect http://amp/swiftifsccode.com/ifsc-code-of-sbi to http://amp/swiftifsccode.com/sbi

Answer (score 6):

**Laravel 301 and 302 redirects using redirect() and route()**

301 (permanent):

```
return redirect(route('events.show', $slug), 301);
```

302 (temporary):

> By default, Route::redirect returns a 302 status code.

```
return redirect()->route('events.show', $slug);
```

Offical Laravel Docs,'Redirect Routes': https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#redirect-routes

Answer (score 5):

You can define a direct redirect route rule like this:

```
Route::redirect('foo', '/bar', 301);
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Laravel 5.8 you can specify `Route::redirect`:

```
Route::redirect('/here', '/there');
```

By default that will redirect with 302 HTTP status code, meaning temporary redirect. If the page is permanently moved you can specify 301 HTTP status code:

```
Route::permanentRedirect('/here', '/there');
/* OR */
Route::redirect('/here', '/there', 301);
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#redirect-routes

Comment: FYI, this has been in Laravel since 5.5