# Laravel 4.1 Redirect all requests from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com with 301 permanent redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-4

**NOT A DUPLICATE TO Laravel, how to redirect as 301 and 302:**

I'm using Laravel 4.1, php 5.4 on Apache webserver. I'd like to redirect all requests coming to

```
 http://www.example.com/whateva 
 to 
 http://example.com/whateva
```

I'm calculating my canonical URL to be placed in the Head section as follows:

```
$canonicalURL = Request::url() . $url_param;
$canonicalURL = str_replace("http://www.example.com","http://example.com", $canonicalURL);
```

How can I do the redirect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel, how to redirect as 301 and 302](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964663/laravel-how-to-redirect-as-301-and-302)

Comment: Thanks... don't think it's a duplicate, the problem here is a bit different, since i want to redirect the whole subdomain. And as we can see below the solution is very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to have bothered you, but I found the answer now.

I added the following code in my `app/filter.php`

```
App::before(function($request){
   //Remove the 'www.' from all domains
   if (substr($request->header('host'), 0, 4) === 'www.') {
      $request->headers->set('host', 'example.com');
     return Redirect::to($request->path());
   }
 });
```

Work like a charm, nothing else needs to be done.